# Easy date selector for Views Exposed Date Filter

Tags: views, datetime

I'm looking for a solution to put "Easy date selector" on the Views Date Exposed Filter, something like a drop-down or links with predefined date range:

- Posts for today
- Posts for yesterday
- Posts for last week
- Posts for last month
- Custom range

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A filters set as "Grouped filters" (as opposed to "Single filter", under "Filter type to expose"), lets you provide a predefined list of options.

[image: Views filter type options]

With Grouped filters, you can setup your fixed list with date filters that are "offset from the current time". For example:

[image: Example of grouped filters showing relative dates]

I'm not sure how you'd accomplish the Custom Range. Perhaps something like the [Select (or other)](https://drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module, or a second filter date filter?